# How to get response from ssh command using expect

Tags: ssh, terminal

currently I am using following code,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set timeout 60

set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set ip [lindex $argv 2]


spawn ssh $username@$ip

expect {
        "*yes/no*" { send "yes\r" }
        "?assword:" { send "$password\r" }
}
expect ">"
send "en\r"

expect "#"
send "con t\r"

expect "(config) #"
send "show interf\r"
interact
```

I have following results in terminal,

```
Interface abcdefgh status:
   Comment:            
   Admin up:           XXX
   Link up:            XXX
   DHCP running:       XX
   IP address:         00.00.00.000 /00
   Netmask:            255.255.255.0
   IPv6 enabled:       no
   Speed:              1000Mb/s (auto)
   Duplex:             full (auto)
   Interface type:     abcdefgh
   MTU:                0000
   HW address:         XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Now I want to read HW address, As I am using expect for automation, Is there any method for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the solution, and sharing for everyone who suffers just like me. 

`send "show interf\r"`

`expect -re {HW address:\s+(\S+)}`

`set hw_addr $expect_out(1,string)`

`puts "the HW address is $hw_addr"`